# Is it a Geometric Sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

If we have these generating functions:
$$G(t)=\frac{t}{e^t-1}$$
and
$$F(t)=\frac{te^{tx}}{e^t-1}$$
We also know that the infinite sum of geometric sequence for $|r|>1$. That is,
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a r^k=\frac{a}{r-1},$$
where $a$=first term $a_1$, and  $r$=common ratio.

Then, I thought that $G(t)$ is a geometric sequence with $a=t$ and $r=e^t$,
and $F(t)$ is a geometric sequence with $a=te^{tx}$ and $r=e^t$ .

Am I right?

Thanks for your any kind help.

Comment: This is very tricky. I tried graphing $G(x)$ in series form and I *think* it diverges. Hope that helps a little. . . .

Comment: You're off by a factor of $-1$:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k = \frac1{1-r}.
$$

Comment: a is common ratio and is constant where t is supposed to be a variable . this  is the difference.

Comment: It kind of works, but the result will be a power series in terms of $e^t$ which only converges for $t < 0$

Answer (score 0):

If $|z|<1$ then 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k = \frac1{1-z}.
$$
So if $e^t<1$, that is, $t<0$, then 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{tk} = \frac1{1-e^t},
$$
and hence
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty te^{tk} = \frac t{e^t-1} = G(t),$$

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty te^{tx}e^{tk} = \frac {te^{tx}}{e^t-1} = F(t).
$$